# Word 2003 will not show up in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I just installed Windows 7 over the holiday and it went swimmingly well. Today I finished up a few things like installed MS Office 2003. That went well too, until I tried to open up Word.

When I try to open up Word on its own, it comes up in the application bar but the application window does not show. I use Word as the editor in Outlook which does work. I also discovered that I can start it up in safe mode and it will work normally. But normal startup just doesn't show me anything. Oddly, if I start typing stuff while the app is selected in the app bar and then try to close it, it pops up a message asking if I want to save it.

I tried running the compatibility utility within Windows 7 but still no dice.

Has anybody seen this issue yet? The other Office apps start normally.

**Edit**:
More info: 
Windows 7 Pro 64-bit. Office is patched up to SP3. And last time I checked, there were no updates either (and fully updated with KBs after SP3) And I did a fresh install of Windows 7.

Comment: What version of Windows 7 are you running?  64-bit?  32-bit?  Home?  Professional?  Have you patched your Office installation with the latest service packs?  Also, did you do an upgrade or a fresh install of Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. So I figured this one out. I'm also running dual monitors so I decided to just use one monitor. I fired up Word and it came up, but in a very tiny tiny, not quite minimized window. I made it larger, saved some temp doc, closed it, re-enabled the second monitor and it works now. Kind of frustrating but it's solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running as an administrator? Seems like something may be wrong with the normal.dot file, but that's just my first wild guess.

Comment: Yeah, one of my co-workers already suggested the normal.dot file. Deleting it didn't do anything. Running as Admin didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the application is appearing way off the screen? You could try using [ForceWindowVisible](http://www.compendiumdev.co.uk/forcedisplay/index.php) to try and get it back on the desktop.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. When you mouse over the app location in the task/app bar, you don't see any kind of preview.